# Browser downloading after virus?

Tags: browser, download, virus, virus-removal

I have cleaned several windows 7 computers from Exploit:Java/CVE-2013-0431.

Everything is back to normal on the computers except for one thing...  User downloads using any internet browser (port 80 and 443) timeout very quickly.  The downloads start but after 200-400kb it is dead.  This includes downloading a file, pulling up a large site, watching a flash video...

Downloading via FTP works fine on the computers, sharing files works fine, any other form of network communication is fine except when it hits a certain size in their browser - and that size isn't totally consistent.

Anything I should be checking?

Comment: If 'cleaning' means anything less than wiping the entire drive then I would start with a format and install or a restore from a known good backup. It will be quicker than trying to fix whatever the virus broke.

Comment: I am heading that route... it is the only issue though.

Answer (score 3):

Nuke it from orbit, that's the only way to be sure.

You may have cleaned the virus of the system, but it left damage to various system files.
And maybe it is not even entirely gone...

You can never be certain you have things back in working order, if you are still using the compromised system as base.
Be safe. Format and re-install.

Comment: Wiping a drive isn't an answer.  Just ignoring that I am trying to figure out what would limit all browsers from downloading larger files... I have never seen this happen so I was wondering the cause.  Not exactly for the easiest "fix".